# Creating a Firefox add-on with a sidebar on the right hand side

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to edit [Daniel Buchner's sidebar library](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/library/1023335/revision/26/) so that the sidebar shows up on the right hand side.  Do I do something along the lines of the following?

sidebar.browser.style.MozBoxDirection = 'reverse';

Comment: did you try it? Another option might be to contact Dan.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work, but I figured it's something along those lines to get the sidebar to show up on the right hand side in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because you would need to change the direction of the sidebar's parent box, not its children. However, that would cause unnecessary fallout (like the default sidebar appearing on the right side and developer tools on the left). So it is better to solve the problem by changing this line:

```js
document.getElementById('browser').insertBefore(clone, splitter);
```

Instead of inserting your sidebar on the left side you can use `appendChild` to add it to the end of the container. You will also have to add your own splitter however - you can clone the sidebar splitter and change its ID.